# Inconveniente al intentar acceder llave , valor de un array y llevarlo en un solo array, en PHP

Tags: php, laravel, array

¿Cómo se pueden unificar varios arreglos en uno?

1. Tengo como matrices lo siguiente:

```html
array:19 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "Plantilla" => "ICOL01"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "Orden_compra_cliente" => "Prueba"
  ]
 ]
```

2. Quiero algo como esto:

```html
[
  "Plantilla" => "ICOL01"
  "Orden_compra_cliente" => "Prueba"
]
```

Gracias

Comment: que esperas tener al final???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

segun lo que colocaste de ejemplo puede hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php

$arr = [
    ['Plantilla'=>'ICOL01'],
    ['Orden_compra_cliente'=>'Prueba']
];
    
    
$flat_array = array();
    
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr)) as $k=>$v){

    $flat_array[$k] = $v;

}

var_export($flat_array);
```

incluso para algo más niveles:

```
<?php

function array_flatten_recursive($array) { 
   if (!$array) return false;
   $flat = array();
   $RII = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
   foreach ($RII as $value) $flat[] = $value;
   return $flat;
}

$array = array( 
    'A' => array('B' => array( 1, 2, 3)), 
    'C' => array(4, 5) 
); 

print_r(array_flatten_recursive($array));
```

Answer (score 1):

Para eso puede usar la función array Y SEPARAR por coma cada valor

```
  $array = array(
      "Plantilla"=>"ICOLO1",
      "Orden_compra_cliente"=>"Prueba"
   )
```

Y si es para combinar todos los valores en uno es de esta manera:

```
$array = array(TU ARRAY);
$t = [];
for($array as $key => $value){
       $t[$key] = $value;
 }
```

De esta manera transformas todo el array en uno.